# How to draw just arrow in gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

In gnuplot, we draw arrow as:

```
set arrow from 0,0 to 1,1
```

I want to make a plot with just arrows and no other data. How can I do this. Right now, after setting arrows, I need to give something to plot, since without that arrows don't get plotted. Is it possible to draw just an empty 'plot' without any data?

I have also seen [online help on gnu](http://security.riit.tsinghua.edu.cn/~bhyang/ref/gnuplot/label2-e.html#4.5) etc., but could not get the answer resolved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you set explicit axis ranges you can plot `NaN` to get a clean set of axes.

Also, `notitle` or `t ''` is needed to hide the key for `NaN`.

```
set xrange [0:5]
set yrange [0:5]
set arrow from 0,0 to 1,1
plot NaN t ''
```

[image: plot output]

Comment: This is correct.  However, rather than all that funky shell redirection/pipe business, you can just do `plot NaN`

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the plot command from the previous:   plot "<echo 10 20" u 1:2

Answer (score 1):

To plot only an arrow with coordinates given in the units of the usual axes, one can use the `vectors` plotting style.

```
# gnuplot 5
$data <<EOD
0 0 1 1
EOD
plot $data u 1:2:3:4 w vectors
```

or

```
# gnuplot 4.x
plot '-' u 1:2:3:4 w vectors
0 0 1 1
e
```